# Api platform dont show mapped superclass in relations

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have a mapped superclass which is extended by all the other entities for ID and the timestamps like so:

```
#[ORM\MappedSuperclass]
#[ApiResource(normalizationContext: [
    'groups' => ['entity:read']])
]
class Entity
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue('AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(['entity:read'])]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    protected ?int $id = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    #[Groups(['entity:read'])]
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    #[Groups(['entity:read'])]
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
}
```

I implement it by adding the entity:read to the normalization.

```
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['address:read', 'entity:read']
    ],
    denormalizationContext: [
        'groups' => ['address:write']
    ],
)]
class UserAddress extends Entity
{
 
    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['address:read', 'address:write'])]
    private Country $country;
```

Now the added side effect is that all my responses contain half an entity:

```
{
      "@id": "string",
      "@type": "string",
      "@context": "string",
      "street": "string",
      "houseNumber": "string",
      "zipCode": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "country": {
        "@context": "string",
        "@id": "string",
        "@type": "string",
        "id": 0,
        "createdAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z"
      },
      "owner": {
        "@context": "string",
        "@id": "string",
        "@type": "string",
        "id": 0,
        "createdAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z"
      },
      "type": "primary",
      "id": 0,
      "createdAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z"
    }
```

expected response:

```
{
      "@id": "string",
      "@type": "string",
      "@context": "string",
      "street": "string",
      "houseNumber": "string",
      "zipCode": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "country": "string",
      "owner": "string",
      "type": "primary",
      "id": 0,
      "createdAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-08-17T12:39:54.368Z"
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent this? I looked at maxDepth but didnt seem to solve the issue.
Thanks.